# Find a free direction in a pointcloud

Tags: python, computer-vision, navigation, point-clouds, a-star

in my setup I have a depth camera looking down on the box. There is one object which should be moved (red rectangle) and obstacles (black things). I need to find a free direction to move the object there on the certain distance (1 m lets say). I have the point cloud of the scene and the transformation between the camera and the ground plane. My idea was to reduce the pointcloud to 2 dimensions, build some sort of occupancy map and try to build a free line pixel by pixel from the objects center with lets say 5 degrees step clockwise. However, I feel that its a too complicated aproach for such task. Is there any simplier solution? Otherwise, how could I take in account objects size? Just add half of the biggest object`s dimesion to each obstacle? But in this case it will consume a lot of safe space as well, because the object is not symmetrical. I use python so any library suggestion would also be very helpful. Thanks!

Setup:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjxFL.png

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: congrats, you're in trouble https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_sofa_problem (and their formulation is a narrow one) it's all heuristics. if you're lucky, your problem isn't too wild and you can apply tons of simplifications. to discuss that, one would need more data (pictures).

Comment: perhaps ask this on the Math Stack Exchange.